# Is it worth creating an object in the controller before passing it off to the model?

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

I'm creating a portfolio page in Codeigniter, and I'm also equipping the site with a simple CMS.

I have a controller that creates portfolio items as follows:

```
public function create_portfolio()
{
    $this->load->model('portfolio_model');
    $this->portfolio_model->insert(
        $this->input->post('title'),
        $this->input->post('short_description'),
        $this->input->post('complete_description'),
        $this->input->post('github'),
        $this->input->post('url')
    );
}
```

An object-oriented approach would be something like this:

```
public function create_portfolio()
{
    $this->confirm_login();

    $this->load->model('portfolio_model');
    $portfolio = new Portfolio(
        $this->input->post('title'),
        $this->input->post('short_description'),
        $this->input->post('complete_description'),
        $this->input->post('github'),
        $this->input->post('url')
    );

    $this->portfolio_model->insert($portfolio);
}
```

With employers increasingly seeking those with OOP skills, I'm trying to evaluate whether the latter approach is effective. In the end, the model that I have would end up accessing all of the instance variables from the Portfolio object in order to insert into the database (I am not using an ORM).

Is there any point to actually grouping all of the input fields into an object before passing it onto the model? I may be phrasing this question the wrong way, but I would love your input.

Comment: I would not go with codeigniter if seeking for the good practices. Start here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0 and see the other related videos from the Google Clean Code Talks.

Answer (score 0):

Since your are passing values to a constructor, the constructor may do validation on the input to ensure it is valid or do some sort of other processing where

`$portfolio->title` may not equal `$this->input->post('title');`

So option 2 would be better.

Comment: But what if my model is responsible form invoking stripslashes and trim onto these fields? Am I getting the MVC order/conventions mixed up?